# Can we sync Azure AD users to our On-Premise AD

Tags: azure

We want to sync users from Azure Ad to our On-Premise AD. We have installed Azure Active Directory Sync tool, that helps to create our On-Premise users to Azure AD, but not wise versa. Please let me know how we can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that there is no way to do it automatically, it will have to be recreated manually. The other way is to create a service using Active Directory Graph API to read data from Azure AD and create them in Local AD.

I had to recreate users manually. I installed Azure Active Directory Module for windows power shell on my VM using [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx), and connected to office 365 using following commands

```
$msolcred = get-credential
```

provided credentials for Azure AD Administrator

```
connect-msolservice -credential $msolcred
```

Further I executed Get-MsolUser cmdlet to get list of users from Azure AD

`Get-MsolUser -maxresults 10000 | Select-Object City, Country, Department, DisplayName, Fax, FirstName, LastName, MobilePhone, Office, PasswordNeverExpires, PhoneNumber, PostalCode, SignInName, State, StreetAddress, Title, UserPrincipalName | Export-Csv C:\Temp\AzureUsers.csv -Encoding UTF8`

After generating list of AD users I executed following cmdlet to create those users in on premise AD

`import-csv C:\Temp\AzureUsers.csv -Encoding UTF8 | foreach-object {New-ADUser -Name ($.username) -SamAccountName ($.username) -GivenName $.FirstName -Surname $.LastName -City $.City -Department $.Department -DisplayName $.DisplayName -Fax $.Fax -MobilePhone $.MobilePhone -Office $.Office -PasswordNeverExpires ($.PasswordNeverExpires -eq "True") -OfficePhone $.PhoneNumber -PostalCode $.PostalCode -EmailAddress $.SignInName -State $.State -StreetAddress $.StreetAddress -Title $.Title -UserPrincipalName $.UserPrincipalName -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -string "Password1" -AsPlainText -force) }`